# Can someone give me an example on how to implement a graph for a group of names?

Tags: java, string, graph

I'm learning about graphs and I'm having a hard time understanding how to implement when the nodes aren't numbers? This is an example code i found online:

```
import java.util.*;
class Graph{
class Edge{
    int v,w;
    public Edge(int v,int w){
        this.v=v; this.w=w;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return "("+v+","+w+")";
    }
}
List<Edge> G[];
public Graph(int n){
    G=new LinkedList[n];
    for(int i=0;i<G.length;i++)
        G[i]=new LinkedList<Edge>();
}
boolean isConnected(int u,int v){
    for(Edge i: G[u])
        if(i.v==v) return true;
    return false;
}
void addEdge(int u,int v,int w){
    G[u].add(0,new Edge(v,w)); 
}
@Override
public String toString(){
    String result="";
    for(int i=0;i<G.length;i++)
        result+=i+"=>"+G[i]+"\n";
    return result;
     }
     }
public class GraphExample {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Graph g=new Graph(10);
    g.addEdge(0, 2, 10);
    g.addEdge(0, 5, 15);
    g.addEdge(2, 5, 10);
    g.addEdge(9, 3, 16);

    System.out.println(g);
    System.out.println(g.isConnected(9,3));
}
}
```

How can I modify this code to represent a graph like this:

[image]

Comment: There are many ways you can represent such graph. For example represent each person (node of the graph) with a class (`Person`). The class can have a `String` attribute to hold the name of the person. The class can also have a `List<Person>` to hold all connected persons.

Answer (score 0):

If the names are unique, then you can put them in `HashMap` and store each name's `hashCode`:

```
Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C").forEach(name -> map.put(name, name.hashCode()));
```

and then put values of name's `hashCode` to graph.

It's called bijection and it's really handy in programming :)

Comment: I fail to see how it answers the question which is about representation of a graph.